# MonoTouch Binding library built using Objective-C static library doesn't call corresponding objective-C method when C# counterpart is called

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin-studio

I've a static library (say myLibrary.a) built from Objective-C Xcode project.

I'm trying to re-use it in Mono Touch iOS application. Following documentation, I built an iOS library project in Xamarin Studio, added myLibrary.a and linked and exported all the methods I want to be available using MyLibrary.cs as shown below. When I build the project it produces myLibrary.dll

```
[BaseType (typeof (NSObject))]
interface TouchTestDriver {

    [Static]
    [Export ("initMyLibrary")]
    void InitMyLibrary ();

    [Static]
    [Export ("startDoingSomethingInteresting:")]
    NSUrl StartDoingSomethingInteresting (NSUrl url);
}
```

Then I built an iOS app (solution) using Xamarin Studio, and included myLibrary.dll in the resources. The classes from myLibrary.dll are visible, so I could do something like this:

using MyLibrary;

and in AppDelegate.cs FinishedLaunching() method, I call the method

```
    MyLibraryLib.MyLibrary.InitMyLibrary();
```

When the app is run in Simulator, it all seems to work fine, but its not calling the objective-C method initMyLibrary(). I confirm this by putting NSLog(), and exit(0). The app doesn't log anything not does it exit.

Am I missing anything? Is there any documentation for this usecase (other than the BindingSample, which I have followed several times w/o any success)

Comment: I can't see anything wrong from your description. Can you gist/pastebin the full build output from Xamarin Studio? Also what happens if InitMyLibrary returns a value - is it a random value in C#, or is it the actual value you return from ObjC?

Comment: is the static library build for the simulator ? could you please show your `AssemblyInfo.cs` file, or your `[LinkWith]` attribute ?

Comment: Is TouchTestDriver, a class or a protocol?